How to resolve conflicts between Alt codes and application hotkeys?
I was trying Alt code.
From wikipedia, to enable it

a user must set or create a string type (REG_SZ) value called EnableHexNumpad in the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method, assign the value data 1 to it, and then reboot or log out/in.

OK. That's great.
Now I can input some Unicode characters. For example, in Notepad, I can input © (U+A9) via Alt + Num + + A9.
However, how can I input  (U+1F419) with the same method?
In Notepad (and most applications), the Alt + F has been bound as a hotkey (File Menu), which conflicts with F in U+1F419.
Is there any way to resolve such hotkey conflict on Windows? (by the simplest manner as much as possible)
Thanks.
P.s. I can copy-paste  in Notepad and display it no problem with font 'Segoe UI Emoji', so it is definitely not a font problem.

A few things here. The Alt+ method of Unicode input only works for characters up to U+FFFF, so it won't work for U+1F419. However, there's an emoji feature in Windows 10 and 11 if you press Win+'.', which allows you to type the octopus . Unfortunately it doesn't have every emoji available, let alone every Unicode character. If the Alt+ and the Win+'.' features aren't sufficient for your needs, you could use Autohotkey to write or install a script that types 5-hex-digit characters. There's also add-ons for browsers such as the emoji keyboard by oinkandstuff, which allows you to search emojis by name and supports the newest version of Unicode (15.1 as of writing this). Here's an Autohotkey 1.1 script that assigns Alt+'-' to work for 5-hex-digit Unicode input:
!NumpadSub::SendUnicode()
SendUnicode()
{
    Input, hex, L5
    Send {U+%hex%}
}


It works, thanks! In addition, the Autohotkey 1.1 script can be converted to the latest Autohotkey 2.0 script by https://github.com/mmikeww/AHK-v2-script-converter
